# HSA Excess Tax Question

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, hsa

I over contributed to my 2023 HSA in January 2024, and already had the excess and the earnings distributed to me in February 2024. The excess contribution was $30.76 and the earnings were $0.76. For my 2023 taxes I followed the prompts in the HSA section for the tax software and it is counting the $30.76 as additional income as it should, but should the earnings on the excess ($0.76) be taxed as income for my 2023 return or in my 2024 return since I took them out in February 2024 (and I’ll get the 1099-SA distribution form for this in May 2024)? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If money was given to you in 2024, it goes in the 2024 taxes, even if you were expecting it in a previous year.

Answer (score 1):

From [IRS Publication 969](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-969), Health Savings Accounts (HSAs), Contributions to an HSA, Reporting Contributions on Your Return, [Excess Contributions](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969#en_US_2023_publink1000204078):

> **Excess contributions.** You will have excess contributions if the contributions to your HSA for the year are greater than the limits discussed earlier. Excess contributions aren’t deductible. Excess contributions made by your employer are included in your gross income. If the excess contribution isn’t included in box 1 of Form W-2, you must report the excess as “Other income” on your tax return.
>
> Generally, you must pay a 6% excise tax on excess contributions. See Form 5329, Additional Taxes on Qualified Plans (Including IRAs) and Other Tax-Favored Accounts, to figure the excise tax. The excise tax applies to each tax year the excess contribution remains in the account.
>
> You may withdraw some or all of the excess contributions and avoid paying the excise tax on the amount withdrawn if you meet the following conditions.
>
> - You withdraw the excess contributions by the due date, including extensions, of your tax return for the year the contributions were made.
> - You withdraw any income earned on the withdrawn contributions and include the earnings in “Other income” on your tax return **for the year you withdraw the contributions and earnings**.

(emphasis mine)

The excess contributions themselves would be included as income for the year that the contributions were made.  In this case, that would be 2023.  If the contribution was made through your employer but not withdrawn through your employer (meaning that the excess contribution is not included in Box 1 of Form W-2), you'll need to include it as "Other Income" on your 2023 tax return.  From what you have said in your question, it sounds like this is the scenario that applies to you.

For the earnings on the excess contribution (in your case, $0.76), the publication says that it needs to be included as "Other Income" on your tax return for the year you withdraw the contributions and earnings.  In this case, since you received this money in 2024, it will need to be added to your 2024 tax return (the one you will file next year).